# My script cycles through 20x20 times, instead of just 20 times. I can't for the life of me work out why

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to display a form, populated with data from a JSON file fetched on document load. It cycles through the array within the data (Where there are 20 items) and creates a form with each cycle, filling it with the data it found.

Firstly, example JSON:

```
{
  "team": {
    "_id": "5c59b190d4dc14030821620e",
    "team": {
      "teamRoster": {
        "teamCoach": "Coach Testerson",
        "players": [
          {
            "playerName": "First Player",
            "playerNumber": "1",
            "playerPosition": "Goaltender"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Second Player",
            "playerNumber": "2",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Third Player",
            "playerNumber": "3",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Fourth Player",
            "playerNumber": "4",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Fifth Player",
            "playerNumber": "5",
            "playerPosition": "Goaltender"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Sixth Player",
            "playerNumber": "6",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Seventh Player",
            "playerNumber": "7",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Eighth Player",
            "playerNumber": "8",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Ninth Player",
            "playerNumber": "9",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Tenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "10",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Eleventh Player",
            "playerNumber": "11",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Twelfth Player",
            "playerNumber": "12",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Thirteenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "13",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Fourteenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "14",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Fifthteenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "15",
            "playerPosition": "Goaltender"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Sixteenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "16",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Seventeenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "17",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Eighteenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "18",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Nineteenth Player",
            "playerNumber": "19",
            "playerPosition": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "playerName": "Twentieth Player",
            "playerNumber": "20",
            "playerPosition": "Forward"
          }
        ]
      },
      "shortTeamName": "TST",
      "teamName": "Test Team",
      "added": "2019-02-05T15:53:52.818Z",
      "updated": "2019-02-05T15:53:52.818Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

Then, the code within the update.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    {{> header}}

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        {{#each team.team.teamRoster.players}}
        text = "<div class='form-group row'><div class='col-md-4'><input id='player" + i + "Name' name='player" + i + "Name' value='{{this.playerName}}' type='text' class='form-control here'></div><div class='col-md-4'><select id='player" + i + "Number' name='player" + i + "Number' selected='{{this.playerNumber}}' class='form-control here jerseyNumber'><option>{{this.playerNumber}}</option></select></div><div class='col-md-4'><select id='player" + i + "Position' name='player" + i + "Position' value='{{this.playerPosition}}' class='form control here position'><option value='{{this.playerPosition}}'>{{this.playerPosition}}</option><option value='Goaltender'>Goaltender</option><option value='Forward'>Forward</option><option value='Defense'>Defense</option></select></div></div>";

        var playerSpan = $('.player');
        playerSpan.append($(text));
        {{/each}}
    }

    $(".jerseyNumber").each(function(){
        var $select = $(this);
        for (n=0;n<=99;n++){
            $select.append($('<option></option>').val(n).text(n))
        }
    });
});
</script>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="body">
        <div class="container" id="page-header">
        <h1><span id="headline">Team Update</span></h1>
            <hr>
            <h3><span id="subheadline"></span></h3>
                <form method="patch" action="/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="teamName" class="col-form-label">Team Name</label>
                        <input id="teamName" name="teamName" value="{{team.team.teamName}}" type="text" required="required" class="form-control here">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="teamShortName" class="col-form-label">Team Short Name</label>
                            <input id="teamShortName" name="teamShortName" value="{{team.team.shortTeamName}}" type="text" aria-describedby="teamShortNameHelpBlock" required="required" maxlength="3" class="form-control here">
                            <span id="teamShortNameHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Three Characters Only</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="coachName" class="col-form-label">Coach Name</label>
                            <input id="coachName" name="coachName" value="{{team.team.teamRoster.teamCoach}}" type="text" class="form-control here">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="imageFile" class="col-form-label">Team Logo</label>
                            <input type="file" class="btn btn-default" name="teamLogo" accept="image/png">
                            <span id="teamLogoHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Currently PNG files only</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>Player Names</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>Player Numbers</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>Player Positions</strong>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <span class="player">
                    </span>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                    <hr>
        </div>

    {{> footer}}
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, the server.js section:

```
app.get('/update/team/:id', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
    Team.findById(id).then((team) => {
        if (!team) {
            return res.render('error.hbs');
        }
        console.log(team);
        console.log(team.team.teamRoster.players[0])
        res.render('update.hbs', {team});
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.render('error.hbs');
    });
});
```

I've tried removing the i loop, or altering the {{each}} line, but nothing seems to work. Any help anyone can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: And what is your exact question ? relevant code ?

Comment: My mistake, accidentally posted. I recall posting questions went through more tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I played with handlebars, but #each is an iterator, and you're using it in the for loop. Dropping that for loop should work